# PGAdmin Docker-compose read email and pass env file

Tags: docker-compose, pgadmin

I'm trying to setup docker-compose with using more secure way of specifying username and password for pgadmin using an env file.  I have set it up (and have other containers successfully using it), but for what ever reason I can't figure out whey i cannot log into pdamin with my creds.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'

services:
  my_db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: my_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5551:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    env_file:
      - ./config/prod.env
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5051:80
    depends_on:
      - my_db

volumes:
    db_data:
    pgadmin:
```

```
#./config/prod.env
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@gmail.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=some_password
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` instead of `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD`. [Here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/container_deployment.html) some references.